# Convert array of objects to comma separated key value pairs javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an arrow of dynamically generated data. The format I have is:

```js
const myRow = [
[{ id: 0},{title: "Task 1"}, { complete: 20}],
[{ id: 1},{title: "Task 2"}, { complete: 40}],
[{ id: 2},{title: "Task 3"}, { complete: 40}],

]
```

Desired row data structure is

```js
const rows = [
  { id: 0, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 ,completed: 690},
  { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 ,completed: 690},
  { id: 2, title: "Task 5", complete: 60 ,completed: 690},
  { id: 3, title: "Task 3", complete: 690 ,completed: 690}
];
```

Most of the solutions I have tried just turns the value to strings which doesn't work for me

Comment: You're getting results for turning them to strings because of the keywords "comma separated" which aren't actually relevant here - you just want to flatten an array of objects into one object with all their properties

Comment: Why don't you fix the code that's creating the original data so it puts things into a single object rather than an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) each array into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Note: I'm not sure where `completed` came from.

```js
const myRow = [[{"id":0},{"title":"Task 1"},{"complete":20}],[{"id":1},{"title":"Task 2"},{"complete":40}],[{"id":2},{"title":"Task 3"},{"complete":40}]]

const result = myRow.map(arr => Object.assign({}, ...arr))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ori Drori, thanks this works. I tweaked the initial code.